# Replace a view with another view dynamically in android?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-videoview

i have added custom view i.e FancyCoverFlow in my xml layout file . i want to replace this view with Video view in same position pro-grammatically. Means other views position should not be changed.those should be displayed as it is in the layout file. but only my custom view should be replaced with video view with same position co-ordinates as of FancyCoverFlow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout"
xmlns:fcf="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@drawable/bga"

android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />      

<imageslideractivty.FancyCoverFlow
    android:id="@+id/fancyCoverFlow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"        
    fcf:maxRotation="45"
    fcf:unselectedAlpha="0.3"
    fcf:unselectedSaturation="0.0"
    fcf:unselectedScale="0.4"
    fcf:scaleDownGravity="0.5"/>
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

 <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:progressDrawable="@null"
    android:thumb="@drawable/middle"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can toggle their visibility from code..Use a FrameLayout there like below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout"
xmlns:fcf="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@drawable/bga"

android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <imageslideractivty.FancyCoverFlow
        android:id="@+id/fancyCoverFlow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        fcf:maxRotation="45"
        fcf:unselectedAlpha="0.3"
        fcf:unselectedSaturation="0.0"
        fcf:unselectedScale="0.4"
        fcf:scaleDownGravity="0.5" />

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@null"
        android:thumb="@drawable/middle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you want to show textView1 but not the textView2 within a click event of a button:

So just do that:

```
textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
textView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

textview2 will disappear and if you set the height of LinearLayout wrap_content then the lower portion will holds the portion of textView1

Just do this with your two view i.e. FancyCoverFlow and Video view

Answer (score 3):

Commonly there is some ways to replacing one view by another view
**Method 1:**
Change Visibility of the views 
e.x

```
textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
textView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Here you are not removing any of the  views just change the visibility.

**Method 2 :**
You can programmatically remove all the childrens of the view and add new views
ex.
You have one `LinewarLayout x;`. And Two children views `TextView y, z;`

Now you want to replace the y, z by another one TextView A.
You can achieve this like the following

```
x.removeAllViews();

and x.addView(A);
```

Here you can't use x,y until the view is re created.

Answer (score 2):

For it purpose you can use fragments instead. Put each of your customViews in Fragments, and then [dynamically](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace) replace it.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout"
xmlns:fcf="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@drawable/bga"

android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />      

 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linDynamic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

 <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:progressDrawable="@null"
    android:thumb="@drawable/middle"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

above xml file i have added linearlayout(linDynamic) now you have to  add or replace your FancyCoverFlow and videoview dynamically.